# How to collapse a list into a string in python?

Tags: python, string, list

Lets say you have a list like `['a', 'b', 'c']` and you want it to look like `'abc'` and you don't want to use some big stupid looking for loop.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
>>> str_list=['a','b','c']
>>> ''.join(str_list)
'abc'
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it's

```
string = ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```