# How to make list elements into string?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I am new to Python and not quit sure how to ask for what I need. In the most basic sense, I would like to turn this:

```
a = ['10', '20', '30']
```

Edit:

It actually:

```
a = [10, 20, 30]
```

into

```
a = ['102030']
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest will be using join with empty string:

```
a = ['10', '20', '30']
a = ''.join(a) #use a as result too
```

You will get:

```
'102030' #a
```

**Edit:**

Since your list is list of integer, you should "stringify" the integers first:

```
a = [10, 20, 30]
a = ''.join(str(x) for x in a)
```

or, if you want to put the single result as string to, then enclose the final result with [...]:

```
a = [''.join(str(x) for x in a)]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The elements in my list don't have single quotes around each integer. Does this matter?

Comment: It does matter. That means you have list of integer not list of string, is it?

Comment: Oh, how can I change it?

Comment: Now I see! Thanks so much Ian!

Comment: So how can I then make that string into a simple number value for a variable? Sorry for the lack of Python terms...

Comment: @NoahSprenger in python it is very straight forward, just reverse it from using `str` to using `int`: `a = int(a)`;

Comment: I have one more question, and I think it should be the last... I need to select every other digit in a number and add them to a string or list ideally. I need to select every other number STARTING with the second (so 1 in python speak). Do you think you can help me?

Comment: @NoahSprenger you could use python slicing to do so - it's incredibly simple to do this. You could look what it means in SO or you could post new question to elaborate your issue. :)

Comment: Ok. I think I will ask the question - sometimes I have trouble interpreting the meaning of other's questions.

Comment: I asked the question. I would love your help if you want to look at the only other question under my account.

Comment: @NoahSprenger I have seen it, I think you should post the question using what you currently have... that is, declaring the list and combining it like what is shown above, then you what is result you got and what you actually expect. Your current question has totally different issue since you have integer (instead of list) and you want to slice it which is unable to be done

Comment: @NoahSprenger answered... please take a look

Answer (score 2):

How about,

```
a = ''.join(a)
a = [a]  # if you want to put the string into a list
```

same question here: [How to collapse a list into a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355248/how-to-collapse-a-list-into-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ['10', '20', '30']

print [''.join(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer after edit:

```
[''.join(map(str, a))] # ['102030']
```